# Fix the error term for aov analysis in R

Tags: r, anova

I have a dataframe "df"

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   120 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id      : Factor w/ 30 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 7 7 7 7 13 13 ...
 $ GroupID : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ score   : num  0.00667 0.48125 0.61538 0.55714 0.23077 ...
 $ Control1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Control2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
```

I have 30 subjects (so id from 1 to 30), divided in 5 groups (GroupID runs from 1 to 5). Each group run 4 experiments, when I set two variables Control1 and Control2 to 0 and 1 respectively (so there are 4 combinations: 00, 01, 10, 11). For each experiment I record a value (variable 'score').

So, subjects 1,2..6 belong to Group 1, subject 7,8..12 belong to Group 2 and so on. Control1 and Control2 are experimental condition, for instance, Control1 == 0 means turn off the light during the experiment, Control2 == 1 means turn on the sound during the experiment, and 'score' is the value I measured from each subject in experiments.

Now I want to analyze the data with 'aov' function. I want to tell R that, Control1 and Control2 are fixed effect variable, and GroupID is random variable. I want to see the interaction of GroupID and Control1 and Control2, as well as interaction between GroupID and Control1, and GroupID and Control2, and so on.

So I did:

```
> summary (aov (score ~ GroupID * Control1 * Control2 + Error(id/(Control1 * Control2)), data = df))

Error: id
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
GroupID    4  2.004  0.5010   6.189 0.00132 **
Residuals 25  2.024  0.0809                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Error: id:Control1
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Control1          1 0.4955  0.4955   13.50 0.00114 **
GroupID:Control1  4 0.3832  0.0958    2.61 0.05974 . 
Residuals        25 0.9177  0.0367                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Error: id:Control2
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Control2          1 0.4132  0.4132  21.261 0.000102 ***
GroupID:Control2  4 0.0982  0.0246   1.263 0.310568    
Residuals        25 0.4858  0.0194                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Error: id:Control1:Control2
                          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Control1:Control2          1 0.3741  0.3741  23.899 4.97e-05 ***
GroupID:Control1:Control2  4 0.1689  0.0422   2.698   0.0538 .  
Residuals                 25 0.3914  0.0157                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Please look at F-value of Control1. It showed the value '13.50', which is the result of Sum Square of Control1 (0.4955) divide to Sum Square of Residuals (0.9177) then multiply with degree of freedom of Residuals (25).

But I want the F-ratio of Control1 should be calculated as: Sum Square of Control1 (0.4955) divided by Sum Square of GroupID:Control1 (0.3822) then multiply to degree of freedom of GroupID:Control1 (4), so it should be 5.186. Also the critical F-value should be calculate based on degree of freedom 4, not by 25. So in this case, it is not significant.

My colleague argued that, the problem may lie at the point that, R understand that GroupID is fixed effect, not random effect, but she does not know R. Anyway, it is just a kind of suggestion.

So, how can I tell R to calculate F-ratio as described above?

My full data:

```
df
    id GroupID       score Control1 Control2
1    1       1 0.006666667        0        0
2    1       1 0.481250000        0        1
3    1       1 0.615384615        1        0
4    1       1 0.557142857        1        1
5    7       2 0.230769231        0        0
6    7       2 0.428571429        0        1
7    7       2 0.218750000        1        0
8    7       2 0.260000000        1        1
9   13       3 0.328571429        0        0
10  13       3 0.412500000        0        1
11  13       3 1.000000000        1        0
12  13       3 0.976923077        1        1
13  19       4 0.256250000        0        0
14  19       4 0.576923077        0        1
15  19       4 0.714285714        1        0
16  19       4 0.573333333        1        1
17  25       5 0.353846154        0        0
18  25       5 0.446666667        0        1
19  25       5 0.885714286        1        0
20  25       5 0.525000000        1        1
21   2       1 0.027272727        0        0
22   2       1 0.050000000        0        1
23   2       1 0.153846154        1        0
24   2       1 0.142857143        1        1
25   8       2 0.161538462        0        0
26   8       2 0.578571429        0        1
27   8       2 0.430000000        1        0
28   8       2 0.727272727        1        1
29  14       3 0.585714286        0        0
30  14       3 0.490000000        0        1
31  14       3 0.836363636        1        0
32  14       3 0.792307692        1        1
33  20       4 0.630000000        0        0
34  20       4 0.738461538        0        1
35  20       4 0.221428571        1        0
36  20       4 0.254545455        1        1
37  26       5 0.092307692        0        0
38  26       5 0.227272727        0        1
39  26       5 0.235714286        1        0
40  26       5 0.410000000        1        1
41   3       1 0.071428571        0        0
42   3       1 0.472727273        0        1
43   3       1 0.527272727        1        0
44   3       1 0.312500000        1        1
45   9       2 0.154545455        0        0
46   9       2 0.168750000        0        1
47   9       2 0.154545455        1        0
48   9       2 0.114285714        1        1
49  15       3 0.187500000        0        0
50  15       3 0.645454545        0        1
51  15       3 0.700000000        1        0
52  15       3 0.845454545        1        1
53  21       4 0.236363636        0        0
54  21       4 0.636363636        0        1
55  21       4 0.750000000        1        0
56  21       4 0.850000000        1        1
57  27       5 0.472727273        0        0
58  27       5 0.350000000        0        1
59  27       5 0.393750000        1        0
60  27       5 0.336363636        1        1
61   4       1 0.015384615        0        0
62   4       1 0.600000000        0        1
63   4       1 0.460000000        1        0
64   4       1 0.458823529        1        1
65  10       2 0.600000000        0        0
66  10       2 0.511764706        0        1
67  10       2 0.414285714        1        0
68  10       2 0.515384615        1        1
69  16       3 0.576470588        0        0
70  16       3 0.600000000        0        1
71  16       3 0.715384615        1        0
72  16       3 0.820000000        1        1
73  22       4 0.250000000        0        0
74  22       4 0.500000000        0        1
75  22       4 0.647058824        1        0
76  22       4 0.684615385        1        1
77  28       5 0.230000000        0        0
78  28       5 0.238461538        0        1
79  28       5 0.200000000        1        0
80  28       5 0.321428571        1        1
81   5       1 0.427272727        0        0
82   5       1 0.716666667        0        1
83   5       1 0.792307692        1        0
84   5       1 0.630000000        1        1
85  11       2 0.092307692        0        0
86  11       2 0.720000000        0        1
87  11       2 0.500000000        1        0
88  11       2 0.790909091        1        1
89  17       3 0.400000000        0        0
90  17       3 1.000000000        0        1
91  17       3 1.000000000        1        0
92  17       3 1.000000000        1        1
93  23       4 0.600000000        0        0
94  23       4 0.684615385        0        1
95  23       4 0.630000000        1        0
96  23       4 0.572727273        1        1
97  29       5 0.353846154        0        0
98  29       5 0.490909091        0        1
99  29       5 0.470000000        1        0
100 29       5 0.325000000        1        1
101  6       1 0.109090909        0        0
102  6       1 0.558333333        0        1
103  6       1 0.320000000        1        0
104  6       1 0.090909091        1        1
105 12       2 0.026666667        0        0
106 12       2 0.418181818        0        1
107 12       2 0.416666667        1        0
108 12       2 0.254545455        1        1
109 18       3 0.245454545        0        0
110 18       3 0.833333333        0        1
111 18       3 0.836363636        1        0
112 18       3 0.946666667        1        1
113 24       4 0.508333333        0        0
114 24       4 0.646666667        0        1
115 24       4 0.581818182        1        0
116 24       4 0.609090909        1        1
117 30       5 0.866666667        0        0
118 30       5 0.745454545        0        1
119 30       5 0.481818182        1        0
120 30       5 0.775000000        1        1
```

Comment: If you know how to calculate this manually, why do you need R to do it for you? If I'm reading your question correctly, this seems like an edge-case to me.

Comment: Also, it's generally preferred to use `dput(df)` to show your data as opposed to printing it `df` as you have.

Comment: Hi @Alex, but it will be painful to calculate all the things (sum of square, degree of freedom, and all kind of these stuffs ...). I believe that Excel even can do it, but R can be done in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer, though not a "solution."

`aov` is a wrapper to the `lm` function to do ANOVA. It is not *designed* to deal with random effects. Thus, as I mentioned in the comments, your application is an edge case.

If you wish to write custom code to handle this edge case, you're more than welcome to. SO is not a free development service, or as was recently mentioned to me in one of my SO questions on C++ "No, we are not here to write code for you. Sorry."

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if something is not clear here. I don't expect that someone write code for me, but if your answer is correct, it is a valid answer.